# How do I read the height or width property of pseudo-element :before using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

I need to calculate the new position of a element who is created by the pseudo class :before.

This element  is a li tag where I display the attribute alt.
The width and height depend of the length of the text that contain the attribute alt.

CSS:

```
.legende:before{ 
position:absolute;
max-width:70%;
bottom:0.2em;
z-index:1;
padding:0.3em 1em;
font-size:1.6em;
content:attr(alt);
}
```

Is it possible to do that and how would I do it?

Comment: Just tried: this returns the dimensions of the related "host" element. http://jsfiddle.net/LQZbU/

Answer (score 0):

No, a pseudo element belongs in the box of its "host" element, so your best bet is to query the `offsetWidth/offsetHeight` of the host element itself.